# Вывести из указанной папки изображения.

Tags: php

Есть папка, например, img. В ней находятся изображения со следующими именами: 1.gif, 2.gif, 3.gif ... 10.gif (имена будут только и только такие). Необходимо вывести средствами php из данной папки картинки с 5.gif по 9.gif включительно. Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($i=5;$i<10;$i++) echo '<img src="/img/'.$i.'.gif">';
```

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Ну а если имена файлов в папке точно не известны, то можно воспользоваться функцией

```
ScanDir(dirname);
```

Она возвращает массив файлов, расположенных в папке `dirname`

Comment: Меня интересует именно мой случай. Про ScanDir мне известно, но всё равно спасибо.